# TFS checkin with mandatory comment field and TFS SDK query

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to do following things using TFS SDK.

1. I would like to implement the Checkin policy so that comments while check-in the file should be made mandatory and once checkin done, I want to get and save the changeSetID and files associated with that checkin event, which I will save to DB.
2. I Want to add some add-in option to the Team menu in VS 2010.
3. If there would be any file selected by user in team explorer and if he selects the option added in Team menu,I would like to get lets say the ChangeSetIDs associated with that file or the file name or the latest changeSetId.
4. Once I get any one of this, on user click of the option which I will add in Team menu. I would like to show the details related to that file in some UI form/web, where user can see the enviroment status[Dev/UAT/Prod] of that file, the lastchangeSetID enviroment and some other details related to project of that file.

Can anybody help me on this or give me the direction to proceed on this task.